# How do I dynamically link lists in WPF with different sizes per row to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to create a datagrid in WPF where two columns are static and after that the columns will be dynamic based on the length of the Parameter list based on the MVVM pattern. The idea is that you will be able to select a distribution type with a dropdown box in the second column and that it will generate the parameters afterward. Each row can have a different size of parameters, upon the selection of the line I will change the header parameter accordingly to fit the parameters. I have not a good idea how to achieve this, could anyone point me in the right direction.

Clarification: The rows should just behave like data grids and be user changeable. Each column of the separate array should have its own header.

The current layout:

[image]

The XAML of the main window

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Tester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Tester"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <DataGrid Name="data" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Distribution Type" Binding="{Binding Dist.Type}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Param 1" Binding="{Binding Dist.Param1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Param 2" Binding="{Binding Dist.Param2}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code of the sample application:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPF_Tester
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Parameter> Data = new List<Parameter>();
            Data.Add(new Parameter() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Dist = new Distribution("static", 1, 0) });
            Data.Add(new Parameter() { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Dist = new Distribution("guassian", 1, 2) });
            Data.Add(new Parameter() { Id = 3, Name = "Sammy Doe", Dist = new Distribution("gaussian", 1, 2) });

            data.ItemsSource = Data;
        }

        //Class with the parameters per row of the datagrid
        public class Parameter
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Distribution Dist { get; set; }
        }

        //Distribution class
        //PROBLEM: Parameters should be a list that can change in size depending on the selected type
        public class Distribution
        {
            public Distribution(string type, int param1, int param2)
            {
                Type = type;
                Param1 = param1;
                Param2 = param2;

                //This is what I would want to work, fill the datagrid with a list of changing size
                //depending on the type of the distribution.
                if (type == "static")
                     ParamList = new List<int> { 1 };  //This with what I would want to fill the datagrid
                else if (type == "guassian")
                    ParamList = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
            }

        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<int> ParamList { get; set; }
        public int Param1 { get; set; }
        public int Param2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**The Basic Question:** How do I dynamically link lists with different sizes per row to the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

You really need the data to go sideways. In your case I would use a `TemplateColumn` of the `DataGrid` and template it as a `WrapPanel` as in the following example:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Parameters">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ItemsControl Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ParametersList}">
                 <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          <WrapPanel />
                     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5"  Margin="3,0" MinWidth="100" >
                          <Grid>
                             <TextBlock>Here you will put whatever you wish to show... </TextBlock>
                          </Grid>
                       </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Although this works it is not entirely what I want, I want it to behave the same as a grid where each value has a separate header. Also I am not sure how to dynamically link the data in the ParmetersList to the TextBlock. If I use the code the content of the TextBlock will just be repeated for the amount of items I have in the list, but not actually display the items themselves.

Comment: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Field1} />`. You can add `TextBlock`s (or any other control) for any other field you have in the `ParametersList` collection.